# How can I get CPU load per core in C#?

Tags: c#, load, cpu-cores

How can I get CPU Load per core (quadcore cpu), in C#?

Comment: Seen that, but thats global load, i need PER core.

Comment: I've found it:
http://www.codegain.com/articles/csharp/windowsforms/how-to-display-processor-usage-of-dual-core-processors.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either use WMI or the System.Diagnostics namespace. From there you can grab any of the performance counters you wish (however it takes a second (1-1.5s) to initialize those - reading values is ok, only initialization is slow)

Code can look then like this:

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

    public static Double Calculate(CounterSample oldSample, CounterSample newSample)
    {
        double difference = newSample.RawValue - oldSample.RawValue;
        double timeInterval = newSample.TimeStamp100nSec - oldSample.TimeStamp100nSec;
        if (timeInterval != 0) return 100*(1 - (difference/timeInterval));
        return 0;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var pc = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time");
        var cat = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Processor Information");
        var instances = cat.GetInstanceNames();
        var cs = new Dictionary<string, CounterSample>();

        foreach (var s in instances)
        { 
            pc.InstanceName = s;
            cs.Add(s, pc.NextSample());
        }

        while (true)
        {
            foreach (var s in instances)
            {
                pc.InstanceName = s;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1:f}", s, Calculate(cs[s], pc.NextSample()));
                cs[s] = pc.NextSample();
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

Important thing is that you cant rely on native .net calculation for 100nsInverse performance counters (returns only 0 or 100 for me ... bug?) but you have to calculate it yourself and for that you need an archive of last CounterSamples for each instance (instances represent a core or a sum of those cores).

There appears to be a naming convetion for those instances :

0,0 - first cpu first core
0,1 - first cpu second core
0,_Total - total load of first cpu
_Total - total load of all cpus

(not verified - would not recommend to rely on it untill further investigation is done)...

Comment: Something must be wrong because the code you provide sometime gives negatives CPU usage percentages.

Comment: `NextValue()` computes the result from `NextSample()`. First result is 0, second is 0 or 100%, the third is the actual value, hence "only 0 or 100" is not a bug.

Comment: @tigrou Same. The `Calculate` is wrong. You might want to use `GetValue()` instead of `GetSample()` and then calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Since cores show up as seperate CPUs to the OS, you use the same code you'd use to determine the load per CPU in a multiprocessor machine.  One such example (in C) is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/MultiCPUUsage.aspx).  Note that it uses WMI, so the other thread linked in the comments above probably has you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

First you need as many performance counters as cores (it takes time, you might want to do this in an async task, or it blocks you UI):

```
CoreCount= Environment.ProcessorCount;
CPUCounters = new PerformanceCounter[CoreCount];
for (var i = 0; i < CoreCount; i++)
    CPUCounters[i] = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", $"{i}");
```

Then you can fetch the value of usage of each core:

```
public float[] CoreUsage { get; set; } // feel free to implement inpc

public void Update() => CoreUsage = CPUCounters.Select(o => o.NextValue()).ToArray();
```

However you might want to call `Update()` three times: the first time you'll always get `0.0`, then second time always `0.0` or `100.0`, and then at last the actual value.

`NextValue()` gives you the instant value, not the mean value over time; if you want the mean value say over 1 second, you can use `RawValue` and calculate the mean as explained here: [PerformanceCounter.RawValue Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.rawvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)