# How to check load on windows server by using C# coding?

Tags: c#, windows-7

I have 6 windows servers, those are working on different locations.

i need to check load on each server from one Server by using C# coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "check load"?

Comment: Checking for available physical memory. Like, if See Task manager in that performance tab we can observe CPU and Memory graphs and also values are displaying i need to get that Memory Value.

Comment: dublicating of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938629/how-can-i-get-cpu-load-per-core-in-c

Comment: why does it have to be C#? Wouldn't WMI or Powershell be more appropriate?

Comment: System load is VERY vague. On most DB systems hard-disk IO is a bottleneck. Using memory load/proc % is completely useless unless you track IO load too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use the `PerformanceCounter` class from the `System.Diagnostics` namespace. It has the following constructor:

```
public PerformanceCounter(
    string categoryName,
    string counterName,
    string instanceName,
    string machineName
)
```

You can see a simple example on [this page](http://zamov.online.fr/EXHTML/CSharp/CSharp_927308.html).