# How to get CPU usage for more than 2 cores?

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I try to get in my program CPU usage divided by a cores. Now I use the PerformanceCounter
and changing the InstanceName between 0 and 1 I have the data from 2 cores.

```
PerformanceCounter pc0 = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "0");
PerformanceCounter pc1 = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "1");
```

How I can get core usage for 3rd, 4th core etc.?

Does anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "2");`  ?

Comment: Also see [SO: how can i get cpu load per core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938629/how-can-i-get-cpu-load-per-core-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I havent used PerformanceCounter before but is there something wrong with doing this?

```
PerformanceCounter pc0 = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "0");
PerformanceCounter pc1 = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "1");
PerformanceCounter pc2 = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "2");
PerformanceCounter pc3 = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "3");
```

Comment: The problem with doing that is you will get an error if the cores do not actually exist. The error will occur as soon as you try and get a value out of the counter (e.g `pc4.RawValue`). However, if you know there are at least 4 cores, then your code will be fine.

Comment: Exactly I try to do this on machine with 2 cores and got error about 'instanceName 2 doesn't exist' so I thought it won't works.
Now I use try-catch exception and works fine on both architecture.
Thanks

Comment: @Spychu My answer will prevent you having to catch an Exception for what really *shouldn't* be an exceptional condition...

Comment: find number of cores from
[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c)
and loop!

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that what you are really asking is "[How do I count the number of cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c)?". This code will count the number of cores, and then create performance counters based on that.

```
int coreCount = 0;
foreach (var item in new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor").Get())
{
    coreCount += int.Parse(item["NumberOfCores"].ToString());
}

PerformanceCounter[] pc = new PerformanceCounter[coreCount];

for (int i = 0; i < coreCount; i++)
{
    pc[i] = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", i.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(pc[i].CounterName);
}
```

Comment: What about if we have support HTT and want to read the logical processor usage ?

Comment: See the accepted answer on the other StackOverflow question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c). This gives details on all the different things you might want to read.

Comment: I have read this before. I have the data about logical cpu quantity etc but I need to read the ProcessorTime of logical cpu.
I'm not sure if I can do this using PerformanceCounter

Comment: Hmmm. I think that the Processor category actually refers to Logical processors, and that the difficulty will be in generating a per-Core processor usage. You'd need to do something like identity which processor pair is running on a single core, then take the average of their usage. I suspect it's more complicated than that though...

Comment: NumberOfLogicalProcessors is right NumberOfCore return core physical core , in my machine (i7) numberOfCore = 4 but NumberOfLogicalProcessors = 8 ; anyway tnx

Answer (score 6):

This might be an old question, but for anyone else looking for a different solution, why don't you use System.Environment?

```
public static List<System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter> GetPerformanceCounters()
{
    List<System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter> performanceCounters = new List<System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter>();
    int procCount = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < procCount; i++)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter pc = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", i.ToString());
        performanceCounters.Add(pc);
    }
    return performanceCounters;
}
```

EDIT: I noticed this only returns the amount of logical processors, not the actual core count.

Comment: Still a nice answer even without the core count.

Answer (score 3):

Some thing like this should also work for your requirement

```
public List<string> GetServerStatus()
{
    List<string> cpuStatus = new List<string>();
    ObjectQuery wmicpus = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
    ManagementObjectSearcher cpus = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmicpus);
    try
    {
        int coreCount = 0;
        int totusage = 0;               
        foreach (ManagementObject cpu in cpus.Get())
        {
            //cpuStatus.Add(cpu["DeviceId"] + " = " + cpu["LoadPercentage"]);
            coreCount += 1;
            totusage += Convert.ToInt32(cpu["LoadPercentage"]);
        }
        if (coreCount > 1)
        {
            double ActUtiFloat = totusage / coreCount;
            int ActUti = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(ActUtiFloat));
            //Utilisation = ActUti + "%";
            cpuStatus.Add("CPU = " + ActUti);
        }
        else
        {
            cpuStatus.Add("CPU = " + totusage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        cpus.Dispose();
    }            
    return cpuStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select NumberOfLogicalProcessors from Win32_Processor").Get())
    coreCount += int.Parse(item["NumberOfLogicalProcessors"].ToString());

PerformanceCounter[] pc = new PerformanceCounter[coreCount];

for (int i = 0; i < coreCount; i++)
    pc[i] = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", i.ToString());
```