# How to get the CPU Usage of each Processor in C#?

Tags: c#, performancecounter, system.diagnostics

I want to measure the cpu usage of each processor.

When I run the following program, I get instance name `2`, `3`, `0`, `1`, and `_Total`. I thought I should get `0`, `1`, `0,_Total`, `1,_Total`.

What does the result mean? How to get the total cpu usage of each processor. Not each core?

```
 class PerfMonitor
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var pc = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time");
        var cat = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Processor");
        var instances = cat.GetInstanceNames();

        foreach (var s in instances)
        { 
            pc.InstanceName = s;
            Console.WriteLine("instance name is {0}", s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think operating systems break things down by CPU - every system monitor I've seen has only had options to see each core or to see a sum of everything.

Comment: You've got 4 processor cores so you got counters for each individual one and for the sum of them.  Hard to guess what you could mean with "0,_Total".

Comment: maybe you have a dual core intel machine so due to hyperthreading it may be showing 4 cores and usage of each core

Comment: As a followup, [this source](http://superuser.com/a/260029/92910) suggests there is no practical difference between multi-core and multi-CPU, so trying to group by CPU is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @hans-passant. "0,Total" is what I got something from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938629/how-can-i-get-cpu-load-per-core-in-c?lq=1)

Comment: The guy probably has more than one processor in his machine.  You don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Windows sees cores as processors, this is not an easy thing to do.  You might start by trying to [determine the number of physical CPUs](http://blogs.adamsoftware.net/Engine/DeterminingthenumberofphysicalCPUsonWindows.aspx), but it is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the result mean?

Your result is this:

```
instance name is 2
instance name is 3
instance name is 0
instance name is 1
instance name is 6
instance name is 7
instance name is 4
instance name is 5
instance name is _Total
```

Each instance is a logical id for the processer (hyper-V logical ones included) except for the last one which is a cumulative instance of all processors on the system.

Comment: Looks to me you have 8 cores.

Comment: @ericyoung yes those are mine, it is 4 physical cores and 4 logical cores.

Answer (score 0):

Download OpenHardwareMonitor, it is open source and contains a dll that you can use to do this