# Visual Studio - CPU meter for individual cores (.net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, cpu

I found a tutorial on the internet about how to make a CPU meter in vb, but I want to make it count the process of all the cores I have. I have a dual core PC, but let's say that I want this program to detect how many cores I have, and count the processes on each individual core.

Now I have this code and I have no idea why it returns a single value, because I have two cores:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim cpuLoad As Integer = CDec(PerformanceCounter1.NextValue.ToString())
    cpuLoad = 100 - cpuLoad
    Label1.Text = cpuLoad.ToString() & "%"
    On Error Resume Next
    ProgressBar1.Value = cpuLoad.ToString()
End Sub
```

Sorry, I forgot to say something about PerformanceCounter1:

- CategoryName: Thread (I'm not shure if this helps but this is what the guy from the tutorial did)
- CounterName: % processor time
- InstanceName: idle/0

Comment: Can't possibly answer this without knowing more details on `PerformanceCounter1`

Comment: Please post your code where you declare the PerformanceCounter, so we're better able to assist on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the code where you declared Performancecounter1.  I believe you are pulling back a total of the thread for all logical processors.  To get where you're going, you will need to have some separate labels and counters.

Here's an example:

```
Dim PcList As New List(Of PerformanceCounter)
PcList.Add(New PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", True)) 'Believe that's all you currently get, TOTAL
For i = 0 To Environment.ProcessorCount - 1
    'Create a counter for each logical processor
    PcList.Add(New PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", i, True)) ' Core i
Next

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        For Each Pc In PcList
            Label1.Text += Pc.InstanceName & "|" & 100 - CDec(Pc.NextValue.ToString) & vbCrLf
        Next
    End Sub
```

Original code I borrowed from [here](http://www.codegain.com/articles/csharp/windowsforms/how-to-display-processor-usage-of-dual-core-processors.aspx)

Here's a prior [question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938629/how-can-i-get-cpu-load-per-core-in-c), but in C#