# Monitoring CPU usage over all cores for a .net application

Tags: c#, .net, cpu-usage

I was wondering if anyone could help with getting cpu usage information for a specific application, I am able to get the usage information identical to what you would see in the task manager using the following [code](http://www.allenconway.net/2013/07/get-cpu-usage-across-all-cores-in-c.html)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: Use a profiler for performance,  not for memory

Comment: I have seen code such as: 
                PerformanceCounter myAppCpu = 
                new PerformanceCounter(
               "Process", "% Processor Time", "app", true);
               double pct = myAppCpu.NextValue();
However this gives one value for the whole cpu and not % per core which is what i am after.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get CPU load per core in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938629/how-can-i-get-cpu-load-per-core-in-c)

Comment: Chris a profiler is a software to analyze code,  not a code to use.

Comment: I know what a profiler is, but i need the cpu information for my program, not for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Sharped - this is not a duplicate, perhaps my poor grammar didn't help but I am after cpu information specific to my application

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to do this.

First one is to use WMI

```
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor");
    var cpuUsages = searcher.Get()
        .Cast<ManagementObject>()
        .Select(x => new
                      {
                          Name = x["Name"],
                          Usage = x["PercentProcessorTime"]
                      }
        )
        .ToList();

    var totalUsage = cpuUsages.Where(x => x.Name.ToString() == "_Total").Select(x => x.Usage).SingleOrDefault();
```

The second is to use a PerformanceCounter foreach core.

```
    int processorCores = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor").Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().Sum(item => int.Parse(item["NumberOfCores"].ToString()));
    var performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter[processorCores];
    for (var i = 0; i < processorCores; i++)
    {
        performanceCounter[i] = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", i.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Correct me if i am mistaken but both of these code samples will give general cpu information (not application specific) across all cores

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago I used the [pdh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373078(v=vs.85).aspx) commands to get various per process information (in my case, CPU, idle and power states). I believe they are now legacy and there is a newer updated set of APIs.

I found these [examples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Use-PerformanceCounter-to-272d57a1) of using performance information from the MSDN website. I haven't tried them.

One note: The names of the counters can be deceptive. Many times, I found that the counter name changed slightly from one generation of windows to the next. As a made up example, "COUNTERINFOPROCESS" might become "COUNTERINFPROCESS". There is also an API for dumping a list of the names of all counters.